# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando hacer una página php con un inicio de sesión copiando un fragmento que me pasó un compañero pero al momento de ejecutarlo me salta ese error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean.

No sé como resolverlo; este es el código:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["login"])){
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','toni','','ssf');

  if(!$mysqli->connect_errno){
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Contrasena = $_POST['pw'];
    $Admin = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Contra = $_POST['pw'];

    if($_POST['Tipo'] == "cliente"){
      $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' AND Contrasena='$Contrasena'");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        setcookie("login",$_POST['usuario'],time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
        $_COOKIE["login"] = $_POST["usuario"];
        $Admin=false;
      }
      else{
        echo "Login Incorrecto";
      }
    }
    else{
      $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' AND Contrasena='$Contrasena'");

      if(!$results || mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
        setcookie("login",$_POST['Usuario'],time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
        $_COOKIE["login"] = $_POST["Usuario"];
        $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
        $Admin= $row["Tipo"] == "Admin" ? true : false;
      }
      else{
        echo "Ni lo intentes";
      }
    }  
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí estas diciéndole a tu código que se ejecute cuando tu query falle

```
if(!$results || mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
                    setcookie("login",$_POST['Usuario'],time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
                    $_COOKIE["login"] = $_POST["Usuario"];
                    $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
                    $Admin= $row["Tipo"] == "Admin" ? true : false;
                }
```

entonces cuando tu query falla no puede ejecutar

```
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
```

por lo cual tu if deberia ser

```
if($results && mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
```

para que se ejecute cuando el query funcione y te retorne resultados.

por otro lado tu query no funcionara por que no estas escapando correctamente, debería de escaparse así:

```
"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario='".$Usuario."' AND Contrasena='".$Contrasena."'"
```

pero esta forma de crear query es muy insegura y fácilmente pueden hacer una inyección sql.

intententa investigar sobre los querys preparados, del tipo

```
if ($result= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT  * FROM  users WHERE  `name` =  ? and pass= ?")) {
        $result->bind_param('ss', $name, $pass,);  
        $result->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es debido, como se afirma en la respuesta anterior, a un error en el if.

Pero, tu código presenta una vulnerabilidad que podría ser peligrosa. Pues es **una muy mala práctica** enviar a la base de datos la consulta SQL completa, es decir, consulta y datos. ¿Por qué?, porque al hacer esos abres la puerta a la llamada Inyección SQL.

Te muestro un fragmento de código en el cual podrás ver un ejemplo de **consultas preparadas**. Es la práctica recomendada para consultar los datos cuando en los mismos intervienen valores que pueden ser tomados de otra parte, como formularios y otros.

Es un elemento a tomar **muy en cuenta** si quieres escribir un código robusto.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pe9t-xzkv)**</kbd>

**Código:**

```
<?php

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ean = ?"; 
$id=4;

//Preparar la consulta
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

//Evaluar si  tuvo  éxito
if ($stmt) {
    /*
      * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
      * Ejecutar
      * Almacenar los resultados
    */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();


    echo "<pre>";

    /*
      * Imptimir los  resultados
      * Si no  esta instalado  mysqlnd  es complicado obtener
      * los resultados en un  arreglo por eso uso una función  propia
    */


    while($row = mi_fetchassoc($stmt))
    { 
            echo "id: ".$row["id"]. " título: ".$row["title"]."\n";


    }

echo "</pre>";

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();




// Función para cuando  no está  instalado  mysqlnd

function mi_fetchassoc($stmt)
{
    if($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        $rs = array();
        $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$rs[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
        if($stmt->fetch())
            return $rs;
    }

    return null;
}





?>
```

**Resultado**

```
id: 38053 título: Hamlet
id: 38054 título: Romeo y Julieta
id: 38055 título: Lo que el viento se llevó
id: 38056 título: No hay amor más grande
id: 38057 título: El Principito
id: 38058 título: El Quijote
```