# mostrar datos de una base de datos mediante función

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema, no puedo mostrar datos de una fila con mysqli y php. 
en localhost lo hacia así y funcionaba:

```
$id = $_SESSION ["id_usuario"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

y podia llamarlo con un echo en cualquier sección del archivo php, ahora que esta en un servidor ocurre un error interno 500 y en el log me muestra Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean, y me muestra la linea con el error:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

revisando sobre el tema mencionan que es porque no esta orientado como objeto, y que lo mejor seria con consultas preparadas como lo mencionan en esta pregunta [Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77557/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-boolean) 
pero no podría poner la información en distintas secciones del archivo php.
Vi que también se puede hacer mediante función así que revisando hice lo siguiente:

```
function MostrarUsuario($id){
        global $mysqli;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam("i",$id);
        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();
    }
```

Y lo mostraría con:

```
$id = $_SESSION ["id_usuario"];
$row = MostrarUsuario($id);

echo $row[nombre];
echo $row[email];
```

Y me sigue saliendo error interno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que [mysqli_stmt::fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) no retorna los valores que estas buscando, si no que inicializa variables vinculadas en una sentencia previa, [mysqli_stmt::bind_result()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Podrias asignarle a una variable `$result`, el resultado de la consulta con [mysqli_stmt::get_result()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'el_user', 'el_passw', 'la_BD');
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    exit('Connect failed: '. $this->connection->connect_error);
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

function MostrarUsuario($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}

$id = $_SESSION["id_usuario"];
$row = MostrarUsuario($id);
$mysqli->close();

echo $row['nombre']; // Esto lleva comillas
echo $row['email'];
```